# Prove that $| |a|-|b| | \le |a-b|$

Tags: proof-writing, absolute-value

Prove that $| |a|-|b| | \le |a-b|$

(1) I square both sides since I know they are positive: 
$$a^2-2|ab|+b^2 \le a^2-2ab+b^2$$
$$|ab| \ge ab$$
Let $m=ab$
$$|m| \ge m$$
Which is part of the definition of the absolute value. 
Is it enough or I need to rewrite my proof?

Comment: Yes, that seems good enough

Comment: A more direct proof is $|a| \le |b|+|a-b|$ which gives $|a|-|b| \le |a-b|$. Switching $a,b$ gives the desired result.

Comment: @copper.hat, it might just depend on what is already assumed to be usable?

Comment: @AnotherJohnDoe: Very good point, I was thinking norms...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It follows from the inequalities $$|a|=|a-b+b|\le |a-b|+|b|\implies |a|-|b|\le |a-b|.$$ Because of symmetry it is

$$|b|-|a|\le |a-b|.$$ Thus you are done.

Comment: This depends on having already proved that $|a+b| \le |a|+|b|$ which  would proven identically to the proof that the OP has posted.